# Accessing fields of trait of an object instance

Tags: scala, oop, inheritance

I created this little Scala worksheet about inheritance and traits in Scala. As far as I understood, one is able to add traits to single object instances and access the methods of said trait in through that object.
So I mixed in Parents with the f4 object of sister, yet I can't access the methods of Parents. The same goes for f1 and Grandparents.

```
abstract class FamilyMember(name: String, birthDate: String, placeOfBirth: String) {
  override def toString: String = this.name;
}

trait Parents extends FamilyMember{
  var children: Array[FamilyMember] = new Array[FamilyMember](0);
  def printChildren(): Unit = for (child <- children ) println(child.toString)
  def isParent(): Boolean = true
}

trait GrandParents extends Parents {
  def printGrandChildren(): Unit = for (child <- children; child2 <- child.asInstanceOf[Parents].children) println(child2.toString)
}

class Mother(name: String, birthDate: String, placeOfBirth: String) extends FamilyMember(name, birthDate, placeOfBirth) with Parents {
}

class Sister(name: String, birthDate: String, placeOfBirth: String) extends FamilyMember(name, birthDate, placeOfBirth) {
}

val f1: Mother = new Mother("Hildegard", "23-7-1952", "Berlin") with GrandParents
val f4: Sister = new Sister("Moni", "19-12-1993", "Frankfurt am Main") with Parents
val f5: Sister = new Sister("Anne", "10-12-2012","Berlin")

//works fine:
f1.isParent
f1.children = f1.children :+ f4

//doesn't work:
f4.isParent
f4.children = f5.children :+ f5
f4.printChildren()
f1.printGrandChildren()
```

The error I get:

```
Error:(30, 4) value isParent is not a member of Sister
f4.isParent
```

But I added it, with the trait.

Comment: **Sister** is not a **Parent**... Try with `val f4: Sister with Parent`, or leave type inference do its job. - BTW, a `var` in a `trait` is a really bad idea.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Wow thanks a lot! I cannot believe I did not see that... (Also thanks for the hint about var!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be somewhat more explicit: by writing

```
val f4: Sister = ...
```

you specify the static type of `f4` is `Sister` and so the compiler will only let you call `Sister`'s methods, whatever `...` is (provided it can have type `Sister`, of course).

Answer (score 1):

As @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez has pointed out in the comments:

> Sister is not a Parent... Try with val f4: Sister with Parent, or
> leave type inference do its job. - BTW, a var in a trait is a really
> bad idea.

Using the following code it works:

```
val f1: Mother with GrandParents= new Mother("Hildegard", "23-7-1952", "Berlin") with GrandParents
val f4: Sister with Parents = new Sister ("Moni", "19-12-1993", "Frankfurt am Main") with Parents
val f5: Sister = new Sister("Anne", "10-12-2012","Berlin")
```